# replace() giving unexpected results

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a script that will find all links from clyp, an audio clip site. I am pretty inexperienced in js, so forgive me if my code is terrible.

In my example, no matter what I do, I cannot get the 'code' variable to return anything even though it is the same exact syntax as the 'replace' variable.

Here is what I have so far:

body:

```
<div class="body"><a href="https://clyp.it/mo3nehzm" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">https://clyp.it/mo3nehzm</a></div>
```

js:

```
function clyp() {
var length = document.getElementsByClassName("body").length
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var body = document.getElementsByClassName("body")[i];
    var body2 = body.innerHTML;
    var code = body2.replace(/([>])(https:\/\/clyp.it\/)([\w]{8})/, "$3");
    var replace = body2.replace(/([>])(https:\/\/clyp.it\/)([\w]{8})/, "$1$2$3");
    body.innerHTML = replace.concat(code);
}
}
clyp();
```

fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mzrt/8zmuktey/

This is not the final product. The last line in the js only serves to show that the 'code' is not returning anything.

Thanks for reading and for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your replace statement that produces the variable code is dropping the ">" that closes the anchor tag. It should look like:

```
var code = body2.replace(/([>])(https:\/\/clyp.it\/)([\w]{8})/, "$1$3")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const clyp = data => data.replace(/(<a.*?>).*?https:\/\/clyp\.it\/(.*?)(<\/a>)/g, '$1$2$3')

const clypAll = selector => {
    const selected = document.querySelectorAll(selector)
    for(let i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
        selected[i].innerHTML = clyp(selected[i].innerHTML)
    }
}

clypAll('.body')
```

```html
<div class="body"><a href="https://clyp.it/mo3nehzm" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">https://clyp.it/mo3nehzm</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to view a result variable that contains html tags by `rendering` the html itself is a bad idea, unless you always want to check the source-code.

In your `code` variable, you actually get this:

```
<a href="https://clyp.it/mo3nehzm" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"mo3nehzm</a>
```

So, you generate a html tag, which is not only invalid but `empty`, hence nothing is shown. So, you also see that this is the content of your `$3`, which means your regex is not matching as you expect it to match.

So, you need to replace it with `$1$3` to get valid HTML - or use a different regex or different approach at all.

```
var code = body2.replace(/([>])(https:\/\/clyp.it\/)([\w]{8})/, "$1$3");
```

leads to

```
<a href="https://clyp.it/mo3nehzm" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">mo3nehzm</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to receive the last 8 characters you can do the following:

```
function clyp() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("body");
  var regex = /href=.*clyp\.it\/(.*?)"/g;
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      var innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML;
      var code = regex.exec(innerHTML)[1];
      document.body.innerHTML += code;
  }
} clyp();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mzrt/8zmuktey/